# Python remove unlinked nodes in all materials scene

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

I found this code to remove all unlinked nodes on a material selected , but I want to edit the code to remove all unlinked node in all the material on the scene, I am very bad coding but I know the power of coding, if someone could help me will be great. thanks.

Original code.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
mat = ob.active_material
#mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Foo") # material Foo
assert (mat is not None and mat.use_nodes), "No material or not node based"
linked_nodes = set()

for link in mat.node_tree.links:
    linked_nodes.add(link.from_node)
    linked_nodes.add(link.to_node)
        
unlinked_nodes = set(mat.node_tree.nodes) - linked_nodes
while unlinked_nodes:
    mat.node_tree.nodes.remove(unlinked_nodes.pop())
```

Comment: are these 3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/If0zc.png to be considered as linked?

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted will get the current active object and a material from that. So you could make it iterate over all materials in the blend like this.

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.node_tree:
        continue  # skip when there is no node tree
    linked_nodes = set()
    for link in mat.node_tree.links:
        linked_nodes.add(link.from_node)
        linked_nodes.add(link.to_node)

    unlinked_nodes = set(mat.node_tree.nodes) - linked_nodes 

    while unlinked_nodes:
        mat.node_tree.nodes.remove(unlinked_nodes.pop())
```

Comment: work perfect.... many thanks